# In water, will sucrose be hydrolysed by water to form glucose and fructose molecules?

Tags: biochemistry, solutions, carbohydrates

If I dissolve sucrose sugar ($\ce{C_12H_22O_11}$) in water, would the water readily hydrolyse the sucrose sugar to form glucose and fructose sugars?

Comment: @M.A.R. Yes, but this question was asked before the other one, shouldn't it be the other way round?

Comment: Also I think if we are comparing these two questions, I can easily imagine two different people with different intents, each wanting to see a version of this similar question. This believe this is a valid case of duplication, if you want to view it that way. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Being marked as a duplicate does not mean anything bad for your question, just that a question with a more comprehensive answer is linked at the top for future readers. Curious that you're linking Dr. Strangedupe, because I'm using precisely the same mentality here. Love the duplication, and stop worrying about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not without a catalyst present. The process is usually performed using [invertase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertase), but some other enzymes with similar activity exist and addition of acid also can catalyse the reaction.